# Ruby on Rails query returns extra column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.9, on Oracle 11g database.

I query the database to get pairs of values [date, score] to draw a chart.
Unfortunately, my query returns triplets such as [date, score, something], and the chart fails.

Here is the query:

```
@business_process_history = DmMeasure.where("period_id between ? and ? and ODQ_object_id = ?", 
first_period_id, current_period_id, "BP-#{@business_process.id}").
select("period_day, score").order("period_id")
```

Here is the result in the console:

```
DmMeasure Load (1.2ms)  SELECT period_day, score FROM "DM_MEASURES" WHERE (period_id between 1684 and 1694 and ODQ_object_id = 'BP-147') ORDER BY period_id
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<DmMeasure period_day: "20140811", score: #<BigDecimal:54fabf0,'0.997E2',18(45)>>, 
#<DmMeasure period_day: "20140812", score: #<BigDecimal:54fa7e0,'0.997E2',18(45)>>, ...]
```

Trying to format the result also returns triplets:

```
@business_process_history.map { |bp| [bp.period_day, bp.score] }
=> [["20140811", #<BigDecimal:54fabf0,'0.997E2',18(45)>], 
["20140812", #<BigDecimal:54fa7e0,'0.997E2',18(45)>], ...]
```

Where does this come from? 
How can I avoid this behaviour?

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: what triplets? From what I can see, you have two attributes per item: 'period_day' (a string representing a date) and 'score' (a BigDecimal representation of a single number).

Comment: Well, I can recognise the value from the database in '0.997E2', but what about 18(45)> ? What is this ?

Comment: moving this to an answer... as it now answers your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what triplets? From what I can see, you have two attributes per item: 'period_day' (a string representing a date) and 'score' (a BigDecimal representation of a single number).

The [ruby BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) is just one way of representing a number.

eg if you play around with them in the rails console:

```
> BigDecimal.new(1234)
=> #<BigDecimal:f40c6d0,'0.1234E4',9(36)>
```

The first part, as you can see, a bit like scientific notation, it contains the significant digits and precision.

To figure out what the `18(45)` is, I had to dig into the [original c-code for the `BigDecimal#inspect` method](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c).
Here's the commenting for that method:

```
/* Returns debugging information about the value as a string of comma-separated
 * values in angle brackets with a leading #:
 *
 * BigDecimal.new("1234.5678").inspect ->
 * "#<BigDecimal:b7ea1130,'0.12345678E4',8(12)>"
 *
 * The first part is the address, the second is the value as a string, and
 * the final part ss(mm) is the current number of significant digits and the
 * maximum number of significant digits, respectively.
 */
```

The answer being: the current number of significant digits and the maximum number of significant digits, respectively